# RabbitMQ Consumer-Increment-Count Configuration In Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have these configurations:

```
    container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(100);
    container.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
    container.setPrefetchCount(1);
    container.setAutoStartup(true);
    container.setConsecutiveActiveTrigger(1);
```

And this works like: starts with 1 consumer and goes on 1 + 1 + 1 + 1....100(max-consumer) with each active consecutive trigger. Is there a way to increase it like: starts with 1 consumer and goes on 1 + 5 + 5 + 5 ... 100(max-consumer) with each active consecutive trigger?

So it increases the consumer count 1 by 1. But I want to change it like 5 by 5 or 10 by 10.

Comment: I am not sure but maybe you can use `setTaskExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15))` something like this to increase consumers or `setStartConsumerMinInterval(100)` because default is 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

No; only one consumer is added for each trigger.

I suggest you open a new feature request: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues